# Manually convert string to sha256

Tags: python, hash, sha256

For example, if I take “Hello World” and go paste it into some online hashing website, or by using this python code:

```
from hashlib import sha256
print(sha256('Hello World'.encode()).hexdigest())
```

it would return "a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e" which represent its hash value.

But what i'm looking for is some document or whatever that allows me to go manually from that text to hash

Comment: As of right now it is highly unclear what it is that you want. Please further specify what you want if you want help.

Comment: Read e. g. https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/cyber-security-tutorial/sha-256-algorithm

Comment: [RFC 6234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6234)?

Comment: I'm looking for some document that describes the sha256 hashing, how it works and how to step by step go from a text value to hash value